# SIGSEGV and mono crash issue while running .NET binary using mono

Tags: c, linux, mono

I have ubuntu 12.04 Linux on my PC and mono-complete package "Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)".

I am going to run one .NET binary using mono and got SIGSEGV signal after running that binary and mono is going to be crashed after that.

I have also got some gdb debug messages on command prompt whihc i have mentioned below.

Thread 2 (Thread 0xb28ffb40 (LWP 20460)) :

```
 #0  0xb7796424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
 #1  0xb77329db in read () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
 #2  0x080e18e7 in read (__nbytes=1024, __buf=0xb2e0867c, __fd=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/unistd.h:45
 #3  mono_handle_native_sigsegv (signal=11, ctx=0xb2e08bcc) at mini-exceptions.c:2208
 #4  0x081209fc in mono_arch_handle_altstack_exception (sigctx=0xb2e08bcc, fault_addr=0x0, stack_ovf=0) at  exceptions-x86.c:1223
 #5  0x0806094d in mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (_dummy=11, info=0xb2e08b4c, context=0xb2e08bcc) at mini.c:5909
 #6  <signal handler called>
 #7  0xb48881dc in ?? ()
 #8  0xb2bcba6b in bulk_interrupt_read_thread (arguments=0xb4888108) at testusb.c:1596
 #9  0xb772bd4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
 #10 0xb766adde in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Thread 1 (Thread 0xb757a700 (LWP 20449)) :

```
 #0  0xb7796424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
 #1  0xb765c690 in poll () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 #2  0xb2c2c984 in ?? ()
 #3  0xb2c2bdb0 in ?? ()
 #4  0xb2c2e2d4 in ?? ()
 #5  0xb2c4e770 in ?? ()
 #6  0xb2c4b86c in ?? ()
 #7  0xb2c4b527 in ?? ()
 #8  0xb2e14518 in ?? ()
 #9  0xb2e139a8 in ?? ()
 #10 0xb2e13648 in ?? ()
 #11 0xb58e3f84 in ?? ()
 #12 0xb58e403e in ?? ()
 #13 0x08064c2c in mono_jit_runtime_invoke (method="GTechUtility.Program:Main ()", obj=0x0, params=0xbfab491c, exc=0x0) at mini.c:5791
 #14 0x081a422f in mono_runtime_invoke (method="GTechUtility.Program:Main ()", obj=0x0, params=0xbfab491c, exc=0x0) at object.c:2755
 #15 0x081a7025 in mono_runtime_exec_main (method="GTechUtility.Program:Main ()", args=0x3be00, exc=0x0) at object.c:3938
 #16 0x080bb80b in main_thread_handler (user_data=<synthetic pointer>) at driver.c:1003
 #17 mono_main (argc=2, argv=0xbfab4ae4) at driver.c:1855
 #18 0x0805998f in mono_main_with_options (argv=0xbfab4ae4, argc=2) at main.c:66
 #19 main (argc=2, argv=0xbfab4ae4) at main.c:97
```

=================================================================
 Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code.
 This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
 application.
 =================================================================

Aborted (core dumped)

Please let me know if any one have idea about this issue.

Comment: mono 2.10.x is obsolete, please upgrade your mono

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Disable increasing amounts of your own/application code until the error goes away.  Then refine, with smaller steps, to see which part/line of your code is causing this.

If in the end, there is absolutely no own/application code left, play with the configuration, version, compiler options, of the libraries you're using.

Sorry I can't give you a detailed answer, but I HTH.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try as per your guidance and let you know the result as soon as possible.

Comment: I got the solution of the above issue but i still have doubt that why that was happened? I am passing reference of structure to .NET Binary and whenever i removed that arguments and made compatible .NET binary based on that argument then it is working fine without any SEGV issue.